# View content of H2 or HSQLDB in-memory database

Tags: hsqldb, h2, in-memory-database

Is there a way to browse the content of an H2 or an HSQLDB in-memory database for viewing? For example, during a debugging session with Hibernate in order to check when the flush is executed; or to make sure the script that instantiates the DB gives the expected result.

Does it exist an addon or a library that you can embed with your code in order to allow this?

Please, mention which one you're talking about (H2 or HSQLDB) in case you have an answer specific to one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inspect in memory hsqldb while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697341/inspect-in-memory-hsqldb-while-debugging)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can run H2 [web server](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) within your application that will access the same in-memory database. You can also access the H2 running in server mode using any generic JDBC client like [SquirrelSQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/).

UPDATE:

```java
Server webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web,-webAllowOthers,true,-webPort,8082").start();
Server server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,true,-tcpPort,9092").start();
```

Now you can connect to your database via `jdbc:h2:mem:foo_db` URL within the same process or browse the `foo_db` database using `localhost:8082`. Remember to close both servers. See also: [H2 database in memory mode cannot be accessed by Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077584).

You can also use Spring:

```xml
<bean id="h2Server" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createTcpServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" depends-on="h2WebServer">
    <constructor-arg value="-tcp,-tcpAllowOthers,true,-tcpPort,9092"/>
</bean>
<bean id="h2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createWebServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,true,-webPort,8082"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" depends-on="h2Server">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:foo_db"/>
</bean>
```

BTW you should only depend on assertions and not on manual peeking the database contents. Use this only for troubleshooting.

N.B. if you use Spring test framework you won't see changes made by a running transaction and this transaction will be rolled back immediately after the test.

Comment: I got error that "true" is invalid option.  Did -webAllowOthers used to take parameter?  With the latest H2 code, it does not take any parameter. Look at "main" method here: http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html

Comment: Like hman mentioned, latest version does not accept "true" parameter so just remove it: `<constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,-webPort,8082"/>`

Comment: New versions follow separate argument convention of

`Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort" ,"9092", "-tcpAllowOthers")`
`Server.createWebServer("-webPort", "8082", "-tcpAllowOthers")`

Comment: In pure Java, you have to remove the "true" parameter, and separate the parameters like this : `Server.createWebServer("-web", "-webAllowOthers", "-webPort", "8082").start();`

Comment: With Spring Boot you can simply set "h2.console.enabled: true" and "h2.console.path: h2-console" in your application.properties file.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz, from H2 docs I understood that both Web and Tcp servers are normally used for server mode. And, indeed, you start a TcpServer with a port specified. How can you access it with jdbc:h2:mem then?

Comment: Was not working for me `Server webServer = Server.createWebServer("-web,-webAllowOthers,true,-webPort,8082").start();`

Comment: Maybe with the version available in 2011 "true" was needed along with "*AllowOthers", but now it throws an error. So for all of the above remove ",true". And commenting "not working for me" without an error message is just lame.

Answer (score 35):

For H2, you can [start a web server within your code](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#startWebServer_Connection) during a debugging session if you have a database connection object. You could add this line to your code, or as a 'watch expression' (dynamically):

```
org.h2.tools.Server.startWebServer(conn);
```

The server tool will start a web browser locally that allows you to access the database.

Comment: Comment for those who are using Spring Data - you can get connection from ApplicationContext in this way:     ((DataSource)context.getBean("dataSource")).getConnection()

Comment: this is also great in a JUnit TestWatcher @Rule

Comment: It even works if you lauch it with "evaluateExpression" in intelliJ while debugging.  (locks the rest of watchs until stopped)

Comment: I auto-wired the `DataSource` instance into my test case and added a method with body `org.h2.tools.Server.startWebServer(dataSource.getConnection());`. Now evaluating that method opens browser. Note that this causes execution to sleep until you disconnect (top-left icon in browser)!

Answer (score 10):

In H2, what works for me is:

I code, starting the server like:

```
server = Server.createTcpServer().start();
```

That starts the server on `localhost` port 9092.

Then, in code, establish a DB connection on the following JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL
```

While debugging, as a client to inspect the DB I use the one provided by H2, which is good enough, to launch it you just need to launch the following java main separately

```
org.h2.tools.Console
```

This will start a web server with an app on 8082, launch a browser on `localhost:8082`

And then you can enter the previous URL to see the DB

Answer (score 4):

With HSQLDB, you have several built-in options.

There are two GUI database managers and a command line interface to the database. The classes for these are:

```
org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManager
org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing
org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool
```

You can start one of the above from your application and access the in-memory databases.

An example with JBoss is given here:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3.2/userguide/html/ch07s03.html

You can also start a server with your application, pointing it to an in-memory database.

```
org.hsqldb.Server
```

Comment: According to the docs, you can use a "manager" with any JDBC connection, so this would work for H2 as well :) http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/dbm-chapt.html

Answer (score 4):

For HSQLDB, The following worked for me:

```
DatabaseManager.threadedDBM();
```

And this brought up the GUI with my tables and data once I pointed it to the right named in-mem database.

It is basically the equivalent of newing up a `DatabaseManager` (the non Swing variety), which prompts for connection details, and is set to `--noexit`)

I also tried the Swing version, but it only had a `main`, and I was unsure of the arguments to pass. If anyone knows, please post here.

Just because I searched for hours for the right database name: The name of the database is the name of your datasource. So try with URL jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource if you have a data source bean with id=dataSource. If this does not work, try testdb which is the default.

Comment: org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing.main(new String[] { "--url", URL, "--user", USERNAME, "--password", PASSWORD});

Comment: Here's some explanation of the parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076005/32453

Answer (score 3):

You can expose it as a JMX feature, startable via JConsole:

```
@ManagedResource
@Named
public class DbManager {

    @ManagedOperation(description = "Start HSQL DatabaseManagerSwing.")
    public void dbManager() {
        String[] args = {"--url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:embeddedDataSource", "--noexit"};
        DatabaseManagerSwing.main(args);
    }
}
```

XML context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.root" scoped-proxy="targetClass"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:mbean-server />
<context:mbean-export />
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a Play 2 controller to initialize the H2 TCP and Web servers:

```java
package controllers;

import org.h2.tools.Server;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Play 2 controller to initialize H2 TCP Server and H2 Web Console Server.
 *
 * Once it's initialized, you can connect with a JDBC client with
 * the URL `jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.1.1:9092/mem:DBNAME`,
 * or can be accessed with the web console at `http://localhost:8082`,
 * and the URL JDBC `jdbc:h2:mem:DBNAME`.
 *
 * @author Mariano Ruiz <mrsarm@gmail.com>
 */
public class H2ServerController extends Controller {

    private static Server h2Server = null;
    private static Server h2WebServer = null;

    public static synchronized Result debugH2() throws SQLException {
        if (h2Server == null) {
            h2Server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
            h2Server.start();
            h2WebServer = Server.createWebServer("-web","-webAllowOthers","-webPort","8082");
            h2WebServer.start();
            return ok("H2 TCP/Web servers initialized");
        } else {
            return ok("H2 TCP/Web servers already initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment to previous Thomas Mueller's post rather than an answer, but haven't got enough reputation for it. Another way of getting the connection if you are Spring JDBC Template is using the following:

```
jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

So on debug mode if you add to the "Expressions" view in Eclipse it will open the browser showing you the H2 Console:

```
org.h2.tools.Server.startWebServer(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection());
```

[Eclipse Expressions View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHdyz.png)

[H2 Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H6LY.png)

Comment: Totally saved my day.

Comment: Alternatively use org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-trace").start() and connect to localhost:8082 using a web browser

Answer (score 1):

I've a problem with H2 version 1.4.190 remote connection to inMemory (as well as in file) with  `Connection is broken: "unexpected status 16843008"` until do not downgrade to 1.3.176. See [Grails accessing H2 TCP server hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803279/grails-accessing-h2-tcp-server-hangs/33718748#33718748)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is it working fine at yours machines, but I had to spend a day in order to get it is working.

The server works with Intellij Idea U via url "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/default".

"localhost:8082" in the browser alse works fine.

I added this into the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" depends-on="h2Server">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/default"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="h2Server" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createTcpServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" depends-on="h2WebServer">
    <constructor-arg>
        <array>
            <value>-tcp</value>
            <value>-tcpAllowOthers</value>
            <value>-tcpPort</value>
            <value>9092</value>
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="h2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server" factory-method="createWebServer" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <constructor-arg>
        <array>
            <value>-web</value>
            <value>-webAllowOthers</value>
            <value>-webPort</value>
            <value>8082</value>
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about comfortably viewing (and also editing) the content over ODBC &  MS-Access, Excel?
Softwareversions::

- H2 Version:1.4.196
- Win 10 Postgres ODBC Driver Version: psqlodbc_09_03_0210
- For Win7 ODBC Client: win7_psqlodbc_09_00_0101-x64.msi

H2 Server:

```
/*
For JDBC Clients to connect:
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/trader;CIPHER=AES;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MVCC=true;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;CACHE_SIZE=131072;CACHE_TYPE=TQ
*/
public class DBStarter {
    public static final String BASEDIR = "/C:/Trader/db/";
    public static final String DB_URL = BASEDIR + "trader;CIPHER=AES;IFEXISTS=TRUE;MVCC=true;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;CACHE_SIZE=131072;CACHE_TYPE=TQ";

  static void startServer() throws SQLException {
        Server tcpServer = Server.createTcpServer(
                "-tcpPort", "9092",
                "-tcpAllowOthers",
                "-ifExists",
//                "-trace",
                "-baseDir", BASEDIR
        );
        tcpServer.start();
        System.out.println("H2 JDBC Server started:  " + tcpServer.getStatus());

        Server pgServer = Server.createPgServer(
                "-pgPort", "10022",
                "-pgAllowOthers",
                "-key", "traderdb", DB_URL
        );
        pgServer.start();
        System.out.println("H2 ODBC PGServer started: " + pgServer.getStatus());

    }
}
```

Windows10 ODBC Datasource Configuration which can be used by any ODBC client:
In Databse field the name given in '-key' parameter has to be used.
[image: ODBC Config]