# Inject array of strings to a bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://            www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="test" class="com.Test">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>aa</value>
                <value>bb</value>
                <value>cc</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is my current XML.
If only `Test` took a List -  everything would be fine.

The problem is that `Test` takes an array of strings.

How to do it in Spring?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use:

```
<constructor-arg>
    <array>
        <value>aa</value>
        <value>bb</value>
        <value>cc</value>
    </array>
</constructor-arg>
```

> An array can contain multiple inner bean, ref, collection, or value
>   elements.     This configuration element will always result in an array,
>   even when being   defined e.g. as a value for a map with value type
>   Object.

Also you can specify a value type which you will be passing:

```
<array value-type="java.lang.String">
  <value>aa</value>
  <value>bb</value>
  <value>cc</value>
</array>
```

**value-type**

> The default Java type for nested values. Must be a fully qualified
>     class name.

Answer (score 4):

instead of `<list>` use

```
<array>
  <value>aa</value>
  <value>bb</value>
  <value>cc</value>
</array>
```

Answer (score 3):

With Spring version 3.2.8 you can use

```
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <value>aa</value>
        <value>bb</value>
        <value>cc</value>
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

without problems.

Answer (score 2):

If the constructor has `String[]` as a parameter (which also includes `String...`), you can provide a comma-separated list:

```
<constructor-arg value="Hindustan Moters,Tata Moters,Ashoka Leyland"/>
```

This is notoriously used to instantiate e.g. H2 DB server as a bean. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309359/view-content-of-h2-or-hsqldb-in-memory-database/7315175).

Not sure which version introduced that.