# Does java spring recognize method signature?

Tags: java, spring, methods, properties, setter

Code:

```
<bean class="myClass" >
  <property name="myProp" value="${some_string}"..
```

in myClass:

```
List<String> myProp;
```

and 2 setters:

```
public void setMyProp(String ...)
```

and

```
public void setMyProp(List<String> ...)
```

Spring container always use method that correspond type of property. Does it possible configure in xml file use setter setMyProp(String ...) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Are you saying Spring tries to use "setMyProp(List<String> ...)" and not "setMyProp(String ...)" which you preferred?

Comment: Why do you need two method?

Comment: Taking a guess, that you want a list of strings for your value.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528250/inject-array-of-strings-to-a-bean-in-spring

Comment: Yes, spring select setter that accept type of property in class, not overloaded method that accept type of parameter supplied.

Comment: Can we use a setter inside a setter to do so..?