# how to set values to locations property to load flyway script files

Tags: flyway

the basic configurations of flywaydb is working great, i have 2 sets of properties one component specific and another environment specific, I have placed component specific under db/migration(default) and i have environment specific that comes from another dependency component and all those scripts are under folders like

```
/dev/scripts
/test/scripts
/prod/scripts
```

how do i pass value to the location property of both db/migration(component specific) and above(env specific) locations dynamically

```
<bean class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="locations" value="?" />
    <property name="initOnMigrate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528250/inject-array-of-strings-to-a-bean-in-spring

Comment: i provided like below,

Comment: i am feeding like <property name="locations" value="db/migration,dev/scripts" /> and i have V001_update.sql in dev/scripts folder and when i try to deploy i am seeing Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found more than one migration with version '001'. by the way i have V1_xxx.sql file under db/migration, so does it treat V001 and V1 as same ?

Comment: Yes, versions are treated numerically. Dot notation is supported.

Comment: sure let me update it and see, by the way when i have comma separated locations, which scripts will execute first ?

Comment: i gave V1.1__update.sql and its failing with Wrong migration name format: V1.1_update.sql(It should look like this: V1_2__Description.sql), here is what i have in both the components,  dev/scripts - V1.1__update.sql                                            db/migration - V1_1__xxx.sql

Comment: i see version is maintained but how do i achieve below scenario, my components are 1 Common, 1 Customer, 2 Sales Order , both Customer and Sales Order uses Common now here is how my files will looks like in each                                                       Common   - V2009__update.sql                                       Customer - V1__customer.sql                                     Sales    - V1__sales.sql                                             i am sure it will complain about "Found more than one migration with version V1",what's the workaround for this ?