# Hibernate created table not able to see in H2

Tags: java, hibernate

I am able to create the table successfully through hibernate in Java application but not able to see the same in the H2 database. May be I need another pair of eyes to look into this problem?

Here is my config file.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:~/hibernateDB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;MVCC=FALSE;MV_STORE=FALSE;FILE_LOCK=NO</property>        
        <property name="connection.username">vijayasunil</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>        
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>       
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>
        <property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.learning.hibernate.dto.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The H2 Console looks like as below

[H2 Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hal0.png)
The Java Hibernate console is saying as table is created.

```
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:04 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:04 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:04 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:~/hibernateDB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;MVCC=FALSE;MV_STORE=FALSE;FILE_LOCK=NO]
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=vijayasunil, password=****}
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:05 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
Hibernate: drop table TEST_DETAILS if exists
Hibernate: create table TEST_DETAILS (userId integer not null, userName varchar(255), primary key (userId))
Mar 22, 2016 11:15:06 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@2250b9f2'
*********
SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])
*********
Hibernate: insert into TEST_DETAILS (userName, userId) values (?, ?)
```

Entity class in Java code as below

```
@Entity(name="TEST_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }   
}
```

Updating the Database by using the below piece of code

```
public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("Test User");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();      
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();     
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using h2 database in embedded mode. The embedded mode database can be opened from one connection only. <a href="http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes">Here</a> is the documentation. Are you accessing the database when the database is already connected from other JVM.

Comment: @Sandeep Suhkhija, I am accessing the database once after completing the execution of the Java Program. Am I answered your question? I am opening the H2 database in default mode. Do I need to open the database in another mode? May I know the details?

Comment: What is the script to create table, insert record? And where do you run these statements?

Comment: Ok, these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803718/view-content-of-embedded-h2-database-started-by-spring and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309359/view-content-of-h2-or-hsqldb-in-memory-database might help.