# not able to view h2 database web console and how to change the default h2 port

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I am new to H2 database. For the development purpose I would like to use H2 database and I am having trouble in configuring it with my spring boot web application. I have gone thru several tutorials and SO threads but none could solve my issue. Below are the trails that I have done and none was successful.

**Requirement**: 
1. H2 data base that I can view with web interface( console view)
2. I would like my data to be persisted even if I stop my running web application or even my machine(laptop) so that I do not have to enter all the data once again and can start from where I have left.
3. Would like to change the default port of console(8080) to my own choice(XXXX).

After viewing [H2 Features](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes) Tried with Server Mode with TCP but was not able to successfully start my application , was not able to view Console(web) application and was not able to change the default port to my own choice of port.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.javasree</groupId>
 <artifactId>familytree.thymeleaf</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>familytree</name>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version> -->
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    <start- class>com.javasree.spring.familytree.FamilyTreeApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- This is a web application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- This is a web application test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring- boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
        tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <!--<version>5.1.36</version>-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Spring boot class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages={"com.javasree.spring.familytree.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { 
 "com.javasree.spring.familytree.web.jpa"})
public class FamilyTreeApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

 @Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application){
    return application.sources(FamilyTreeApplication.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers","-webAllowOthers").start();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(FamilyTreeApplication.class)
    //.bannerMode(Mode.CONSOLE)
    .build().run(args);
}
}
```

application.properties:

```
    server.contextPath=/familytree
    server.port=7030

    # JPA properties
     spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
    spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

    spring.jpa.show-sql=true

    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace 


    #H2 config
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.h2.console.path=/h2
    spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
    # Datasource
     spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8084/~/test;MODE=MYSQL;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Exception that I am getting:

```
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost:8084" [90067-196]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:457)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:334)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:116)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:100)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
```

Let me know if it's required to post any more code or any other details to better understand the issue.

Comment: my `spring.datasource.url` property has this value `jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` - can you try this? (without tcp protocol)

Comment: my application is able to create tables and run but I am not able to view the web console at "http://localhost:8080/h2/"

Comment: I see... Check if my answer is helpful then

Answer (score 2):

With Spring Boot, you can configure your H2 console servlet like this:

(hint: make sure the right libraries are imported)

```
import org.h2.server.web.WebServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean( new org.h2.server.web.WebServlet());
        registration.addUrlMappings("/h2-console/*");
        registration.addInitParameter("webAllowOthers", "true");
        registration.addInitParameter("webPort", "7777");// <-- the port your wish goes here

        return registration;
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to access H2 via your URL `http://localhost:7777/h2-console`

(with help of [Spring Guru](https://springframework.guru/using-the-h2-database-console-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security/), [H2 Console Settings](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html?highlight=webPort&search=webPort#console_settings))

Comment: I already have this Bean configured in my application except the part of adding parameters "webAllowOthers" and "webPort". I have added the two parameters as per your answer and I still face the same problem.
"Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost:7777" [90067-196]"

Comment: @GhostRider your `spring.datasource.url` looks off to me but I have no time at the moment to debug it.  Can you see if **[this answer helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28657208/600486)** ? - It has configuration of the TCP server as well as the WebServer (for the console access) perhaps seeing all the pieces of the puzzle together will work?

Answer (score 1):

I had this similar kind of issue when I was trying to use H2 db with Spring Security, after some debugging I find out we have to add the paths in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extending class.

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()

        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/h2/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/h2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

//to avoid X-Frame-Options header of Spring Security. 
 http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
```

reference:[X-Frame-Options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-frame-options)
[spring guru](https://springframework.guru/using-the-h2-database-console-in-spring-boot-with-spring-security/)