# H2 DB in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, h2

I am running a very basic `spring boot` app in an `alpine docker` container with in memory `H2` database on `AWS`. Unfortunately, `webAllowOthers` is not set, so i cannot access the `H2` console.

Is there any way to access the data in the db?

I can sh into the container, but i dont know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve it, in case anybody needs it in the future:

The H2 console has a tool to back up any DB to a .sql file ( accessible in the TOOLS menu ), but since the in memory DB only exists in the running process, it cannot be accessed with H2 Shell, only through the Console which is embedded in the spring boot app.

The H2 Console uses a lot of javascript, so in a command-line-only environment it was almost impossible to use it with command-line browsers ( felt like using VI for the first time... ), but checking how a locally running, accessible console works, gave the answer:

The Script tool uses the following request argument format (change it according to your config):

```
tool: Script
args: -url,jdbc:h2:mem:testdb,-user,sa,-script,~/backup.sql
```

So to backup the db:

- sh into the container
- `wget http://localhost:8080/h2`. The HTML source will have a link to `login.jsp?jsessionid=xxxxx`. Use this session ID in the curl command.
- Post the needed data to the `Script` tool in an URL encoded format:

```
curl -d "tool=Script&args=-url%2Cjdbc%3Ah2%3Amem%3Atestdb%2C-user%2Csa%2C-script%2C%7E%2backup.sql" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:8080/h2/tools.do?jsessionid=xxxx
```

If you did everything right, the backup SQL should be in the given place.

Answer (score 0):

this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49741935/4280315

... to the question *"not able to view h2 database web console and how to change the default h2 port"*, may help.

It worked for me with my spring-boot application in a remote server. I'm **not using Docker**, though.