# How to control H2 driver version in Grails 3 Gradle project?

Tags: java, grails, h2, grails-3.0

How to control `H2` driver version in `Grails`/`Gradle` project?

Having problems with running `Grails 3` app with `H2` I found this answer: [Grails accessing H2 TCP server hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803279/grails-accessing-h2-tcp-server-hangs) stating it may be caused by driver version difference.

My IDE reports `Grails` app uses `1.3.176` version of `H2`, while my server has `1.4.190`. So, I would like to upgrade app's `H2`, but can't find where it is defined. I sought all project files and found no version definition.

**UPDATE**

My current `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.2.RELEASE"
}

version "0.1"
group "multipleparentsgrails"

apply plugin: "spring-boot"
apply plugin: "war"
apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to specify it like any other dependency

`runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.190"`

Comment: In your `build.gradle` under `dependencies`

Comment: But how does it work now if currently there are no any `H2` described at all?

Comment: If it isn't specified at all it must be included by another dependency. Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: You can run a dependencyReport through gradle to see where its being included. Really it shouldn't matter and adding the dependency for the later version should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are many dependencies which may use H2.  grails, hibernate, others.

I would go into your project.  Let's say it's $HOME/projects/myproj.

1) Do a dependency report.  Pipe it into grep so you don't have to wade through a 1,000 line report, and see what versions of H2 are being used.

```
cd $HOME/projects/myproj
./gradlew dependencies | grep 'H2'
```

2) Find the highest version number, and then explicitly include this in your build.gradle to force every dependency to use the most current version:

```
dependencies {
    // all the other dependencies

    runtime "com.h2database:h2:1.4.190"  // where 1.4.190 is the most
                                         // current version.  as i
                                         // type this it is 1.4.191
                                         // according to maven central

}
```