# Can't connect to MySql server with hibernate and JBoss using persistence api

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss

I tried to use the persistence api in my Java EE app in order to connect to a MySql DB, but the JDBC connection doesn't work. 
I'm using a JBoss 7.1.1 Server and Hibernate as persistence framework.
I created a persistence.xml and added a new datasource to the standalone.xml of my JBoss server.
I'm a novice in working with Java EE, JBoss and the Persistence API so I'm not sure if my configurations are correct, but I'm certain that my MySql server is running correctly.

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="WebAppPersistenceUnit">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/WebAppDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>webapp.data.AccountPlan</class>
        <class>webapp.data.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

standalone.xml datasource:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/WebAppDS" pool-name="WebAppDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:3306/webapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>root</user-name>
            <password>******</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

server log:

```
...
21:52:38,840 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
21:52:38,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/WebAppDS]
21:52:38,958 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory D:\Program Files\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
21:52:38,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found jboss-javaee-webapp.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called jboss-javaee-webapp.war.dodeploy
21:52:38,998 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jboss-javaee-webapp.war"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
21:52:39,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primary
21:52:39,231 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment jboss-javaee-webapp.war
21:52:39,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JNDI bindings for session bean named MemberRegistration in deployment unit deployment "jboss-javaee-webapp.war" are as follows:

    java:global/jboss-javaee-webapp/MemberRegistration!org.jboss.tools.examples.service.MemberRegistration
    java:app/jboss-javaee-webapp/MemberRegistration!org.jboss.tools.examples.service.MemberRegistration
    java:module/MemberRegistration!org.jboss.tools.examples.service.MemberRegistration
    java:global/jboss-javaee-webapp/MemberRegistration
    java:app/jboss-javaee-webapp/MemberRegistration
    java:module/MemberRegistration

21:52:39,326 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: jboss-javaee-webapp.war
21:52:39,344 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71)
21:52:39,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [jboss/datasources/jboss-javaee-webappDS]
21:52:39,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'jboss-javaee-webapp.war#primary'
21:52:39,501 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
21:52:39,506 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
21:52:39,507 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
21:52:39,508 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
21:52:39,524 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
21:52:39,625 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
21:52:39,817 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
21:52:39,827 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
21:52:39,829 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
21:52:39,835 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
21:52:39,838 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
21:52:39,866 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
Connected to server
[2016-08-05 09:52:40,041] Artifact HomeWebApp:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
21:52:40,115 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
21:52:40,367 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop sequence hibernate_sequence
21:52:40,367 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) Sequenz "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" nicht gefunden
Sequence "HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
drop sequence hibernate_sequence [90036-161]
21:52:40,372 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-7) HHH000230: Schema export complete
21:52:40,395 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment jboss-javaee-webapp.war
21:52:40,744 INFORMATION [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) für Kontext '/jboss-javaee-webapp' wird initialisiert.
21:52:41,212 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /jboss-javaee-webapp
21:52:41,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
21:52:41,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 4074ms - Started 205 of 282 services (76 services are passive or on-demand)
21:52:41,455 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "jboss-javaee-webapp.war"
21:52:41,523 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "HomeWebApp_war_exploded.war"
21:52:41,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for WebAppPersistenceUnit
21:52:41,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named DataManager in deployment unit deployment "HomeWebApp_war_exploded.war" are as follows:

    java:global/HomeWebApp_war_exploded/DataManager!webapp.data.DataManager
    java:app/HomeWebApp_war_exploded/DataManager!webapp.data.DataManager
    java:module/DataManager!webapp.data.DataManager
    java:global/HomeWebApp_war_exploded/DataManager
    java:app/HomeWebApp_war_exploded/DataManager
    java:module/DataManager

21:52:41,675 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
21:52:41,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
21:52:41,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'HomeWebApp_war_exploded.war#WebAppPersistenceUnit'
21:52:41,683 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: WebAppPersistenceUnit
    ...]
21:52:41,702 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
21:52:41,710 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:253) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:119) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Verbindung ist unterbrochen: "unexpected status 1308622848"
Connection is broken: "unexpected status 1308622848" [90067-161]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:553)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:109)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:373)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:267)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 30 more

21:52:41,727 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/WebAppDS
21:52:41,729 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
21:52:41,729 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
21:52:41,730 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
21:52:41,731 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
21:52:41,742 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
21:52:41,744 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (MSC service thread 1-4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:368) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:452) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Verbindung ist unterbrochen: "unexpected status 1308622848"
Connection is broken: "unexpected status 1308622848" [90067-161]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:553)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:109)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:373)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:267)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 28 more

21:52:41,760 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/WebAppDS
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:67) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:368) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:452) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/WebAppDS
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:390)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:464)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:129)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000658: Unexpected throwable while trying to create a connection: null
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:371)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:329)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Verbindung ist unterbrochen: "unexpected status 1308622848"
Connection is broken: "unexpected status 1308622848" [90067-161]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:553)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:109)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:373)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:267)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:110)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:94)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 28 more

21:52:41,778 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000230: Schema export complete
21:52:41,844 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /HomeWebApp_war_exploded
21:52:41,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "HomeWebApp_war_exploded.war"
[2016-08-05 09:52:41,979] Artifact HomeWebApp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
...
```

Comment: take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803279/grails-accessing-h2-tcp-server-hangs

Comment: Remove the hibernate.dialect property from your persistence.xml because it is both wrong and redundant

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but it doesn't solve my problem.
Federico, I can't find the connection to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using H2 database here instead of MySQL.
You need to create a separated module in JBoss for mysql jdbc driver and then configure it in standalone.xml.

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

Also, your connection string is wrong. It should be something like

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapp
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now with the mysql driver. I also removed "<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>" from my persistence.xml because it caused errors.