# Visualize the content of H2 with Swing

Tags: java, swing, h2

I am using H2 in my Swing application. I have seen [View content of H2 or HSQLDB in-memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309359/view-content-of-h2-or-hsqldb-in-memory-database).

But, I want to know **how can I see the content of** H2 when there is no web server, since I am working with Swing?

I used to visualize the H2 with `devtool` when I work with Spring MVC, but here there is no controller.

Comment: Look [Squirrel SQL client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), download sources and try understand it :).

Comment: Or adapt the plugin cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2761825/230513).

Comment: Note that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.